# Which Stack Exchange site is best suitable for questions about Kubernetes?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On Stack Overflow, some of my questions about [Kubernetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes) and related tools were closed almost immediately.

Where should such question be posted?

Comment: Depending on the question itself it might be [su], [sf] or [devops.se]

Comment: I took a look on SO [kubernetes tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes). and it is far from "every question about Kubernetes and related tools are closed almost immediately". Don't throw false assumptions based only on the fact your own question was closed.

Comment: Joysn: I kindly request you to change your first statement as it is inaccurate. My answer shows broad numbers on a few sites Stack Overflow, the site with the largest number of questions tagged [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes). Also, please add at least one sample question. Note: You should also consider asking for guidance to understand the closing of the questions that you have posted or interest you on Stack Overflow Meta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard and ChatGPT Stan: Sorry for the generalization in my statement, it was not my intention. I saw other questions about Kubernetes on SO, but could not figure out why mines were closed. I was also considerung Super User, Server Fault, Dev Ops, but as ChatGPT Stan pointed out in his answer, the figures on SO led me to believe SO is still the place where most Kubernetes related questions are asked. With the feedback and clarifications here I will and can do better now. Thank you guys :)

Comment: A option to "move" a question to another SE site when it is closed would be nice :)

Comment: `A option to "move" a question to another SE site when it is closed would be nice` - It is much easier (and arguably involves less clicks), for all concerned, just to copy your post from the undesirable site and paste it into a new question on your new target site (whilst deleting the original post yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackexchange.com/search?q=kubernetes returns +154k results.

The first two results are from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). Their [kubernetes tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) has 110 questions. This site might be suitable if you were an Ubuntu user and developer.

There are a few other sites, the first three based on the results page and the last two based on markalex's comment to the question.

- Super User's [kubernetes tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) returns +200 questions. This site might be suitable if you have a question about using computer hardware and software as an end-user.
- Unix and Linux's [kuberketes tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) returns 183 questions. This site might be suitable if you were a user of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.
- Stack Overflow's [kubernetes tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) returns +50k questions, <s>but only [500 are open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkubernetes%5D%20closed%3A0)<sup>1</sup></s>. This site is suitable for programming questions. I added more about this site below.
- Server Fault [kubernetes tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) +2k questions. This site is suitable if you are a system and network administrator.
- DevOps [kubernetes tag](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) +800 questions. This site is suitable if you are a software engineer working on automated testing, continuous delivery, service integration and monitoring, and building SDLC infrastructure.

Notes:

1. The results are capped because my search on Stack Overflow was done anonymously.

Considering that there are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow and that most questions that are closed immediately are usually deleted automatically, it's fair to say that your claim about Stack Overflow is overgeneralizing or has a bias that is unclear due to the lack of details.

Before posting a question, clarify the kind of help you need. If you need to ask a question on Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange Network site, read the guidance on the Ask Question page, including the links.

If you post a question on a topic / tag that already has many questions, ensure that your question,

1. It is according to the site scope. I.E., not all questions about Kubernetes are on-topic in Stack Overflow; remember that Stack Overflow questions should be about programming and tools used to do programming. [Kubernetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes) is a system used to accomplish a broad range of tasks related to software development; not all of such tasks are on-topic in Stack Overflow. It's worth mentioning that some tags have excellent tag usage guidance, and some even include tips and resources. This varies from tag to tag. [Karl's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392655/1395520) describes the content of the Stack Overflow's *kubernetes* tag wiki.
2. It wasn't asked before,
3. If similar questions were asked before, please mention the most relevant and why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: It appears that the open kubernetes tag questions shown to you are limited. However, as I have +30k rep on SO, I can see that there are "56,286 results" on the results page.

Comment: Out of 59,445 total questions for the tag on SO, only 962 [are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkubernetes%5D+closed%3A1). I'd say pretty normal, and about the average closure rate, nothing specific to that tag, which means it's just fine to use it on SO.

Answer (score 5):

> every question about Kubernetes and related tools are closed almost immediately

No, only ones that are off topic are closed.

The generally appropriate ways to find out which Kubernetes questions are on topic for Stack Overflow are:

1. Read the **tag description**. It says:

   > KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. A good rule of thumb is, if it happens outside the pod, it's probably off-topic. If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably OK.

   You can find this description by hovering over the tag on any Kubernetes question, by clicking through to the [page for questions with the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes), or, when asking a question, starting to type the tag name and then **looking at** the suggestions window **before** clicking to apply the tag to your question.
2. Read the **general topicality guidelines for Stack Overflow.**

   These can be found in the Help Center, as:

   - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
   - [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

   as well as on the Stack Overflow Meta, as:

   - [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476)

   In particular, the first links explains that Kubernetes questions on Stack Overflow - **like any other question** - need to be about "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to **software development**". That is: **not** about to using Kubernetes merely to **run** the code (i.e., something you do "outside the pod" to make the code run properly "inside the pod").
3. If you still have doubts about a specific question, ask **on the Stack Overflow meta**, not the general Stack Exchange one.

I see that you personally have asked three questions in that tag on Stack Overflow recently, and two of them were closed. This is a quite poor sample size from which to conclude that "almost every" such question is closed. (You should also understand, as a Stack Overflow user, the value of [doing your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), which in this case [is quite easy](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkubernetes%5D+closed%3A0).)